# Autohotkey remap > and < on italian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, remap

I have a small problem I cant find the solution to:

On my italian keyboard one key holds the two simbols "<" and ">":

- [key] = "<"
- [shift]+[key] = ">"

I'd like to remap them so that the result ins inverted as I use > much more than <.
I can't find a way to write this in ahk. I tried with

```
<::>
+>::<
```

and

```
<::>
>::<
```

The result with the above is that both pressing the key and shift+key returns ">".

I understand what "confuses" ahk but I can't find a workaround.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#UseHook   ; prevents the Send command from triggering the hotkey itself

<:: Send >
+<:: Send <
```

Comment: Or you could add the $ sign to prevent self triggering: $<:: Send >  and  $+<:: Send <